# Vue add event listener to slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-slot

So I have this `<Dialog />` component that extends vuetify's `<v-dialog />` default.

In order to avoid having to pass a `onClose` method to the `DialogContent` component, I'd rather it `$emit('close')`.

But I can't make my slot listen to this event. :(

Here's the code:

```
// Dialog.vue

<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-model="dialog"
  >
    <!-- forward other slots -->
    <template
      v-for="(_, slot) of otherSlots"
      v-slot:[slot]="scope"
    >
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>

    <template v-slot:default="{ on, attrs }">
      <slot name="default" v-on="on" v-bind="attrs" @close="onClose" />
    </template>
  </v-dialog>

</template>

<script>
  import {reject} from '@/utils/object';

  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    computed: {
      otherSlots() {
        return reject(this.$scopedSlots, 'default');
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dialog: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onClose() {
        this.dialog = false;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Usage:

```
      <Dialog persistent>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            My button
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <DialogContent />
      </Dialog>
```

`onClose` is never called.

Any idea why?

Here's a sandbox to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-event-listener-to-slot-ktemg9

Thanks

Comment: Could you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help with debugging this issue

Comment: Try `v-on="{ on, close: onClose }"`

Comment: @Naren it doesn't work :(

Comment: @aphextwix I just added a codesandbox link, the issue happens there too.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger - I think this could set you on the right path - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942544/emit-event-from-content-in-slot-to-parent

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying several of the solutions there, without a chance until now :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sooo I finally succeeded to do what I wanted:

`Dialog.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog>
    <slot name="default" :onClose="onClose" />
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Usage:

```
<template v-slot:default="{onClose}">
  <DialogContent @close="onClose" />
</template>
```

or to have a more vuetify-like syntax:

`Dialog.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog>
    <slot name="default" :on="{close: onClose}" />
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Usage:

```
<template v-slot:default="{on}">
  <DialogContent v-on="on" />
</template>
```

I wish those props (or events) could be forwarded without having to pass them explicitly, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible. :( Otherwise vuetify would do it for its `activator` slots.

Answer (score 1):

You problem come from the fact that the `$emit` emit the function to the parent div, which is your case is the `App.vue` and not the `Dialog.vue`.

---

To solve your problem, you can add a ref to your Dialog and trigger the close function from the div

```js
<div class="text-center my-12">
   <Dialog persistent ref="myDiv">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
         <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> Click me </v-btn>
      </template>
      <DialogContent @close="onCloseFromParent" />
   </Dialog>
</div>

...

methods: {
    onCloseFromParent() {
      this.$refs.myDiv.onClose();
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My idea was to isolate the `<Dialog />` logic from the `<DialogContent />` so that the latter doesn't need to know about the former, besides this `onClose` method. I'm loosing this benefit with your solution and there is not so much reason to separate them, as `<DialogContent />` has to know about the ref. Ain't there any other solution? I reckon in React this would be trivial, which is why I feel like it should be doable.